# Automatically generate sequence number on Google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new on google app script.
I would like to use google sheets automatically insert running sequence number on E2 column (job number).

(eg. i had 5 column, A name,B city,C age,D email,E job number)[image: Picture]

I searched on internet and found this formulas is very useful, but the problem is my code had script to remove duplicates, once I run the 'removeduplicate' script. my formulas will disappear and this will caused sequence number stop running.

```html
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if(row[0] == newData[j][0] && row[1] == newData[j][1]){
  duplicate = true;
}
//      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
//        duplicate = true;
//      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: Why not just `=SEQUENCE(5,1)`

Comment: Could you please provide a copy of the spreadsheet you're working on (free of sensitive information), as well as the outcome you expect? Also, do you want to use Apps Script, or formulas would also be appropriate?